# AWS CDK - How to invoke function Fn.cidr?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I am trying to invoke function `Fn.cidr('10.0.0.0/16', 256, '8');` using AWS CDK (typescript https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/core/fn.html#core_Fn_cidr), but so far this function keeps returning an array of 1 with a cidr value of 0. It seems like this function doesn't work, does anyone knows how to use this function and have a working example?

I was expecting this function to work as described in https://blog.james.rcpt.to/2018/03/16/aws-vpcs-calculating-subnets-in-cloudformation/

Example:

```
const subnetCidrs = Fn.cidr('10.0.0.0/16', 256, '8');
console.log('length'+subnetCidrs.length);
for(let cidr in subnetCidrs){
    console.log('cidr: '+cidr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that instead of

```
for(let cidr in subnetCidrs){
        console.log('cidr: '+cidr);
}
```

it should be

```
for(let cidr of subnetCidrs){
        console.log('cidr: '+cidr);
}
```

it should be `let ... of` instead of `let ... in`